# display nothing if array value match id

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I have an array with products that has a field `ID_Masina` with values that i dont want to display if that `ID_Masina` match the `$_GET['id']`; My code only exclud the product for the first ID_Masina from the array it should exclude it for all matches. Here is my code:

```
$id = $_GET[ 'id' ];
foreach ( $produse as $produs ) {

  $pieces = explode( ',', $produs[ 'ID_Masina' ] );
  foreach ( $pieces as $piece ) {
    if ( $piece == $id ) {
      break;
    } else {
      echo '<div class="pungi">
                    <img src="images/produse/' . $produs[ 'ID_Produs' ] . '/' . $produs[ 'Poza' ] . '">
                    <p>' . $produs[ 'Nume' ] . '</p>
                    </div>';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you print_r($pieces)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `in_array`

```
$pieces = explode(',', $produs['ID_Masina']);
if(in_array($id, $pieces))
break;
```

Comment: thnx i removed the foreach and used in_array and it worked, thnx again :)